# Why it says that super() takes atleast 1 argument

Tags: python, inheritance

```
    class Member():
    def __init__(self, MemberName, MemberID, SubcribtionPaid):
        self.__MemberName = MemberName
        self.__MemberID = MemberID
        self.__SubcribtionPaid = False
    def SetMemberName(self):
        print(MemberName,self.__MemberName)
    def SetMemberID (self):
        print(MemberID,self.__MemberID)
    def SetSubcriptionPaid(self):
        print(SubcribtionPaid,self.__SubcribtionPaid)





class Jmember(Member):
    def__init__(self,MemberName,MemberID,SubcribtionPaid,DateofJoining):
        super().__init__(MemberName,MemberID,SubcribtionPaid)
        self.__DateofJoining = DateofJoining
    def SetDateofBirth(self):
        print(DateofBirth,self.__DateofJoining)



NewMember = Jmember("Armeen","1245","True","12/3/2015")
NewMember.SetMemberName()
NewMember.SetMemberID()
NewMember.SetSubcriptionPaid()
NewMember.SetDateofJoining()
```

I basically copy pasted the code.I used pycharm. I still dont get how to use code block. I dont know what to do.

Sorry if i caused a problem.

I wrote a code in python,where one class inheritates the attributes of another class. When i run the code , error occurs on line 26 saying that super() takes atleast 1 argument .Even though i wrote the arguments. Did I make a mistake there. [The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yo1h.png), [the traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Kw3.png)

I want to see the output of the new member that includes member name, id , subcribtion paid and date of joining. But error is shown.

Comment: Instead of linking to an image, it would be better to post your snippet in code blocks so people could copy/paste it to play with the code if they want to. You can do the same thing with the traceback, so that it displays it nicer in your post. use 3 back-ticks before and after your code to use code blocks.

Comment: Also, post the full traceback. The actual error may be occurring before the reported line.

Comment: You don't have code on line 24 that you linked to.  Are you pointing to the correct code?

Comment: I am new to this site. How do  i use the code blocks? What is a tracback? Sorry for asking silly questions.

Comment: Traceback is your error message stack that tbm edited into a codeblock for you. But you need to include the full error message.

Comment: Codeblock is the way to format you code so that it displays nicely in your post. You add 3 backticks (above your tab key) before and after the section of code that you want to format.

Comment: Also, you seem to have an extra space on line 19 after `super()` that may be producing the error. Anyway, you should not have spaces before member accesses.

Comment: @Niayesh Isky Good catch...I missed the space.

Comment: @ArmeenHossain it's not helpful to remove code, and especially not to replace it with an image. Anyone trying to help will be unable to cut and paste your code to try it out. You're likely going to have your question downvoted out of existence if you don't try to help those helping you.

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: I edited my post to reflect your added code. When I said early to use codeblock, I meant the codeblock function in the editor used to post your question. I guess I confused you with CodeBlocks the IDE application.

Answer (score 1):

Updated my post to reflect your posted code:

1. You said that you are using PyCharm. pay attention to the red squiggly lines under sections as they are pointing out errors.

First error: you did not have a space between def and **init**

```
def__init__(self, MemberName, MemberID, SubcribtionPaid):
```

Second Error: found in your class function calls:
You do not have to call the class that is essentially what (self) is doing

```
def SetMemberName(self):
        print(MemberName,self.__MemberName)
```

Third error: was found in your Traceback
You were trying to call a function that you forgot to create

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sumbody/Projects/Python/MemberTest2/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    NewMember.SetDateofJoining()
AttributeError: 'Jmember' object has no attribute 'SetDateofJoining'
```

Here is the working code:

```
class Member():
    def __init__(self, MemberName, MemberID, SubcribtionPaid):
        self.__MemberName = MemberName
        self.__MemberID = MemberID
        self.__SubcribtionPaid = False
    def SetMemberName(self):
        print(self.__MemberName)
    def SetMemberID (self):
        print(self.__MemberID)
    def SetSubcriptionPaid(self):
        print(self.__SubcribtionPaid)

class Jmember(Member):
    def __init__(self,MemberName,MemberID,SubcribtionPaid,DateofJoining):
        super().__init__(MemberName,MemberID,SubcribtionPaid)
        self.__DateofJoining = DateofJoining
    def SetDateofBirth(self):
        print(self.__DateofJoining)

    def SetDateofJoining(self):
        print(self.__DateofJoining)



NewMember = Jmember("Armeen","1245","True","12/3/2015")
NewMember.SetMemberName()
NewMember.SetMemberID()
NewMember.SetSubcriptionPaid()
NewMember.SetDateofJoining()
```

Some advice, when learning to code and debug your own code, it is not a bad thing to take some code that runs and then break it. It sounds weird, but in doing so you will learn to recognize errors when seen in the editor and at runtime. Happy coding!